# Rails view - separate entry by slash on each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At my view I have the following code

```
<% @merchant.working_hours.open_hours_today.each do |h| %>
  <%= h.open_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)  %> -
  <%= h.close_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)  %> 
<% end %>
```

The code display the following:

```
Sun: 00h00 - 04h00 08h00 - 22h00
```

I want to achieve the following (the slash between times)?

```
Sun: 00h00 - 04h00 / 08h00 - 22h00
```

I've tried the each_with_index method without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. However, I would probably make a helper method in my model or in a decorator that would generate the Open - Close times. This would come in handy if you're displaying it in multiple parts of your application.

```
<%= @merchant.working_hours.open_hours_today.collect { |h| "#{h.open_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)} - #{h.close_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)} }.join(' / ') %>
```

So it could look like

```
<%= @merchant.working_hours.open_hours_today.collect { |h| h.business_hours }.join(' / ') %>
```

Comment: Kobaltz, How you suggest to do the helper method?

Any material to recommend me?

Comment: Within the model, you can declare a method `def business_hours .... end` and put the string interpolation in there.

Comment: But how can I pass the h inside the interpolation on the method? Sorry if it is too simple. I'm pretty new to ROR

Comment: My bad! I'm trying to do that to the wrong model.

Thank You! =)